# Есть ли аналог include_once('header.html') в Node.js (handlebars)?

Tags: node.js, шаблонизаторы, handlebars, express

В PHP, чтобы подключить header.html к текущему файлу, достаточно было в первой строке этого файла написать `include_once('header.html')`. Как сделать что-то подобное в Node.js с шаблонизатором handlebars? Нашёл как создать общий шаблон для всех страниц, но это мне не подходит, нужно просто в нескольких файлах подключить header.hbs. Как это сделать?

Подозреваю что это можно сделать через контроллер, но просто добавляя ещё одну строчку `res.render('header');` ничего не получается...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

В точке входа (app.js/server.js/index.js) регистрируем частицу и указываем к ней путь (в моём случае /views/partials/footer.hbs):

```
hbs.registerPartial('footer', fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/partials/footer.hbs', 'utf8'));
```

И в нужном месте вашего .hbs файла вставляем частицу через:

```
{{> footer }}
```

Comment: а где должен находится этот файл js, если в проекте используется gulp?